# How to express a version range for Github Action dependency

Tags: github-actions

In a GitHub workflow, I may use a versioned Github Action. The [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsuses) states:

> We strongly recommend that you include the version of the action you are using by specifying a Git ref, SHA, or Docker tag number. If you don't specify a version, it could break your workflows or cause unexpected behavior when the action owner publishes an update.

As far I know, the version can be: a branch, ref, or a commit SHA1.

Is it possible to express more constraints such as a version **range**? An imaginary syntax:

```
jobs:
  my_job:
    steps:
      - name: My action
        uses: myAction@[1.1, 1.234]
```

It would means "use MyAction with a version between 1.1 and 1.234". Is there a way to express that kind of version constraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's possible as in theory looks not.

In `github actions`, every customized action's syntax is `githubuser/repository`.

It represents for a real github repo: E.g.`actions/setup-node` as `https://github.com/actions/setup-node`

The github actions engine surely need to download the source code from these repository, and use a git concept (Hash, commit, branch, tag) to find the correct source to run the action. If we allow a range, then really don't know which commit of action's source code should be used.

Comment: But, it's possible to reference the major version. Doesn't it mean that a workflow may get all remote references?

Comment: You may want to have a look for [Semantic versioning for GitHub Actions](https://michaelheap.com/semantic-versioning-for-github-actions/). `Move the major version tag (v1, v2, etc.) to point to the Git ref of the current release.`,   it’s is additional effort to update your tag each time you make a new release. Action owner will be responsible to update it to a git ref usually a new release, so when you use this major version, in fact it already binding to one git ref by owner.

Comment: You help me by highlighting this sentence that I missed. But I disagree with "in theory looks not". It would have been possible to list remote references before any checkout. But GitHub chose to do it differently. An example: git ls-remote --tags 'git@github.com:actions/checkout.git'